# Using SQL table join to use a value from one table as a reference to a value in another (primary key)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables stored on phpmyadmin, 'gigs' and 'bands'. 
gigs: "gigID, gigBand, gigDate" 
bands: "bandID, bandName, bandGenre...."

gigBand is a integer which corresponds to the bandID. I am aiming to diplay all the available gigs, but show the actual band name rather than the number. I have read table joins are the easiest way of doing this, and I have no trouble displaying the data of 'gigs' on the webpage. 
But managing to display the name rather than the value is proving very difficult.

Any advice, or even an example of the code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh come on. A bit more research effort please. :-)

Comment: Can we see what you have at present? I think giving you the solution isn't helpful, to be honest. Please edit any improvements into your question, rather than adding them as comments.

Comment: A couple of recommendations about column naming: using snake-case (`gig_id`) rather than camel-case (`gigID`) as it can save you headaches later on (specifically in cases where your database uses case-sensitive entity names). Foreign keys are usually called `table_id`, so `gigBand` would be usually best as `band_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a MySQL `JOIN` to pull the records of two related tables.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

```
SELECT * from gigs
INNER JOIN bands ON gigBand = bandID
```

This is pretty basic stuff though, so I would strongly recommend taking the time to do a bit more research. This seems like a good place to start:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/index.htm

Comment: I don't think these sorts of questions should be answered, at least not in its present form. The question is so un-researched as to be off-topic, and giving the answer without encouraging any prior effort will encourage more questions of the same quality _and_ fail to teach the OP how to think for themselves. Downvoting, with apologies.

Comment: Everyone has different skill levels and approaches. The question is basic, but not badly formed. Most importantly an attempt has been made to tackle the problem. I would rather coach someone by providing a concise answer and steering them down a more constructive learning path than say "go away and come back when I think you're asking better questions"

Comment: Thanks - I agree with the sentiment expressed. My quibble is that there was not even a start of a `SELECT` in the question, which would have been my (very low) minimum bar.